# R: Modelling estimates for the factors and 'sub-factors' of a predictor variable within a GLM

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, interaction, predictor

To take a simple example, let's say the model contains a dichotomous predictor variable with the factors {Group X, Group Y}, where all observations can be categorized into one of the two groups. However, for 50% of the data, it's possible to break down the factors further into mutually exclusive sub-groups as follows:

{Group X: a,b,c},
{Group Y: d,e,f}

So for a dataset containing 12 observations we might have something like this:

[image]

At the moment I have fitted the model on the main Group variable (with other predictor variables) and have derived an estimate for X and Y, but now would like to come up with an estimate for each of the sub-group factors. Presumably this can be done by splitting the data containing the sub-group factors into a new dataset and modelling the GLM off that using the more granular factors, but not sure how to incorporate/allow for the other 50% of data. Alternatively I did consider including an interaction term on the main model as follows:

```
glm(Response ~ Group / Sub-Group +...)
```

which will derive an estimate for X and Y and an additional estimate for {a,b,c,d,e,f} that I can retain in my model if significant.

Do either of these approaches work or is there a better alternative option?

Comment: I think what you want is `glm(Response~Group+Subgroup)`. Alternatively, you can create a new variable which is a merge of Group and Subgroup, and use this in the model.